# C# ускорить запись в файл

Tags: c#, строки, потоки-данных

Доброго времени суток!

У меня есть такое задание:

> Разработайте ПО, которая будет разбивать числа от 1 до 1 000 000 000
> на группы, при этом числа в каждой отдельно взятой группе не делятся
> друг на друга...

Эти группы надо записать в файл. В общем - все хорошо до 100 млн. Записывается быстро(ну, или я так думаю) - 20 сек на разделение на группы, 20 сек на запись, 800 Мб веса.
Но если поставить хотя бы 200 млн - то все, ошибка переполнения памяти.
Из того, что вычитал и понял - `BufferedStream` ускоряет процесс.
Последний вариант к которому пришел:

```
private static void FullCalculate(long numN, string filePath)
    {
        string newFilepath = filePath.Insert(filePath.IndexOf('.'), "_inGroup");

        if (File.Exists(newFilepath))
        {
            File.Delete(newFilepath);
        }
        StringBuilder nums = new StringBuilder("");
        int count = 2;
        
        Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();
        Stopwatch st2 = new Stopwatch();
        st.Start();
        **using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new BufferedStream(File.OpenWrite(newFilepath), 2 * 1024 * 1024)))**
        {
            nums.Append($"Группа {count - 1}: {count - 1}.\r");//Не стал мучаться с выводом 1 группы
            // в цикле, потому что она статична - "Группа 1: 1."
            //nums.AppendLine();// Убрал AppendLine  в надежде, что это повлияет на процесс
            nums.Append($"Группа {count}: ");
            for (int i = 2; i < numN + 1; i++)
            {
                if (i == Math.Pow(2, count))
                {
                    nums.Append(".\r");
                    //nums.AppendLine();
                    nums.Append($"Группа {count}: ");
                    count++;
                }

                nums.Append(i + " ");
            }
            nums.Append('.');
            st.Stop();

            st2.Start();
            sw.Write(nums); //запись в файл разбитых по группам чисел
            st2.Stop();
        }
        st.Stop();
```

Я пробовал сначала вот так:

```
 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Filepath))
```

По скорости выполнения и ошибкам, так же как и в последнем варианте.

Вопрос, собственно:
**Можно ли что то еще изменить, чтобы, если не повысить скорость, то хотя бы избавиться от ошибок???**

По поводу переполнения памяти примерно понимаю - нужно записать StringBuilder в файл и продолжить дальше разделять на группы. И тогда(по  идее) все запишется. **Это верное направление или есть еще какие-нибудь варианты?**

P.S.: Условия такие, что массивы использовать нельзя, делать в одном цикле.

Само разбиение на группы должно иметь примерно такой вывод(N =8):

Группа 1: 1.

Группа 2: 2 3.

Группа 3: 4 5 6 7.

Логика - разбивать по степеням 2-ки(вдруг нужно)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если решать в лоб, то получится как-то так, но вы делаете слишком много лишних вычислений. И генерируете просто огромного размера строки в памяти, это медленно.

```cs
private static void FullCalculate(long numN, string filePath)
{
    string newFilepath = filePath.Insert(filePath.IndexOf('.'), "_inGroup");

    if (File.Exists(newFilepath))
    {
        File.Delete(newFilepath);
    }
    int count = 2;

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new BufferedStream(File.OpenWrite(newFilepath), 2 * 1024 * 1024)))
    {
        sw.WriteLine($"Группа {count - 1}: {count - 1}.");//Не стал мучаться с выводом 1 группы
            
        sw.Write($"Группа {count}: ");
        for (int i = 2; i < numN + 1; i++)
        {
            if (i == Math.Pow(2, count))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(".");
                sw.Write($"Группа {count}: ");
                count++;
            }

            sw.Write(i + " ");
        }
        sw.WriteLine(".");
    }
}
```

Я бы решал как-то так.

```cs
private static void FullCalculate(long numN, string filePath)
{
    string newFilepath = filePath.Insert(filePath.IndexOf('.'), "_inGroup");
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(newFilepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 1024 * 1024, false)))
    {
        int count = 1;
        long threshold = 1;

        for (long i = 1; i <= numN; i++)
        {
           if (i == threshold)
           {
               sw.Write($"Группа {count++}: ");
               threshold *= 2;
           }
           sw.Write(i.ToString());
           if (i == threshold - 1)
               sw.WriteLine(".");
           else
               sw.Write(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

И вот когда ясно, что память используется эффективно, уже можно начинать играться с буферизацией.

Кстати, `FileStream` имеет свой внутренний буфер. В дополнительном создании `BufferedStream` нет необходимости.

Еще можно распараллелить генерацию данных и запись на диск на 2 потока. Есть такой шаблон многопоточного проектирования - Producer/Consumer. Это когда один поток генерирует данные, а второй потребляет, и они друг друга не ждут. Самый простой представитель реализации этого шаблона - `BlockingCollection`

```cs
private static void FullCalculate(long numN, string filePath)
{
    string newFilepath = filePath.Insert(filePath.IndexOf('.'), "_inGroup");
    BlockingCollection<string> items = new BlockingCollection<string>();
    Task task = Task.Run(() => WriterLoop(newFilepath, items));
    int count = 1;
    long threshold = 1;

    for (long i = 1; i <= numN; i++)
    {
       if (i == threshold)
       {
           items.Add($"Группа {count++}: ");
           threshold *= 2;
       }
       items.Add(i.ToString());
       if (i == threshold - 1)
           items.Add($".{Environment.NewLine}");
       else
           items.Add(" ");
    }
    items.CompleteAdding();
    // здесь всё сгенерировано
    task.Wait();
    // здесь всё записано на диск
}

private static void WriterLoop(string path, BlockingCollection<string> items)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 1024 * 1024, false)))
    {
        foreach (string item in items.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            sw.Write(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Хм, я уже пробовал записывать каждый раз. Но получается непростительно долго - 1 гб веса, минут 10 грузил, после чего я скидывал задачу...
С предложенным кодом то же самое.
И я не могу использовать цикл в цикле.
Но File.Create - согласен, да. Спасибо!

Comment: @Paycom что значит "не могу использовать цикл в цикле"? По условию? Ок, я могу переписать. Вы попробуйте воткнуть буферизацию в то что я вам дал.

Comment: да, по условию. Один цикл - то есть без вложенных. 
Хм, воткнуть буферизацию ..? То есть использовать BufferedStream? Попробую

Comment: @Paycom переписал с одним циклом. Еще проще получилось.

Comment: @Paycom Кстати, `FileStream` имеет свой внутренний буфер. Переписал код с заданием размера буфера, настройте его по вкусу. В дополнительном создании `BufferedStream` нет необходимости.

Comment: А почему `FileStream`  внутри `StreamWriter`?? Они так должны работать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129298/discussion-between-paycom-and-aepot).

Comment: @Paycom конструктор SW принимает Stream. По умолчанию он его закрывает клгда закрывается сам. Поэтому, почему нет?)) Я бы жаже сказал, так правильнее, чем растаскивать на 2 using. Вы же все равно бы забыли передать `leaveOpen: true`, почему бы сразу не подстроиться под это поведение?

Comment: @aepot - а я просто пришел в комментарии поаплодировать!

Comment: @S.H. пишу код по памяти с мобильника, не тестирую, могут быть косяки. )

Comment: @aepot - у меня тоже бывает - выхожу из вагона метро, и еще минут 10 на лавочке в метро заканчиваю ответ на вопрос... Нет, к Вашему коду претензий нет, наоборот!